# How to capture command-line output with python logging?

Tags: python, shell, logging, command-line, stdout

I am writing a script to anonymize metadata, and I am setting up a logging system to record how the script is carried out each time it receives a subject. The script pushes and pulls information from an online server, and uses a "curl" shell commands to do so. When I execute the script, I get an output in the shell that I would like to be recorded in the log file, but I don't know how to capture it.

At the moment I have the logger configured as:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='/path/to/logging_test.txt',filemode='a',format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then I execute the command to modify the metadata once I've pulled it from the server,

```py
os.system(cmd)
```

Which outputs into the shell something like the following:

```py
{
   "ID" : "dshbjhdoqwdjwebfie",
   "Path" : "/subjects/dshbjhdoqwdjwebfie",
   "Type" : "Subject"
}
```

Which I would like to have in the log textfile. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using [os.popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) instead of `os.system`, to get the output as a string:

`output = os.popen(cmd).read()`

then you can log it like any other string content

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! It did take over a minute to process though, I wonder if there is a method that is quicker.